# .Add() method not working when building a list utilizing a "for" loop in C#

Tags: c#, list, winforms, for-loop, checkbox

I'm a C# novice.  I'm working on a form which presents 10 rows of “data” with each row being controlled by the state of the leading checkbox.  The row layout is: checkbox + label + combobox + combobox + textbox. When a user initially accesses the form only the checkboxes are enabled. Selecting (checking) a checkbox enables the controls in that row. Selecting a lower level box “activates” all rows above it and deselecting a higher level box “deactivates” all rows (if any) below it. If rows containing user input are deselected the deselected rows “revert” to initial condition. All action regarding the form controls is triggered by changes to the checkbox state. I am able to accomplish the objectives through brute force (only showing code for one checkbox state change but the code is similar for all checkbox changes):

```
private void placeLevelCheckBox09_.CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (placeLevelCheckBox09.Checked == false)
    {
        placeLabel09.Enabled = false;
        PlaceComboBox09.Enabled = false;
        TypeComboBox09.Enabled = false;
        PlaceComboBox09.Text = "";
        TypeComboBox09.Text = "";
        initialzeTypeDisplay09();
        return;
    }
    placeLabel09.Enabled = true;
    PlaceComboBox09.Enabled = true;
    TypeComboBox09.Enabled = true;
    placeLevelCheckBox00.Checked = true;
    placeLevelCheckBox01.Checked = true;
    placeLevelCheckBox02.Checked = true;
    placeLevelCheckBox03.Checked = true;
    placeLevelCheckBox04.Checked = true;
    placeLevelCheckBox05.Checked = true;
    placeLevelCheckBox06.Checked = true;
    placeLevelCheckBox07.Checked = true;
    placeLevelCheckBox08.Checked = true;
}
```

My code seems clumsy and inefficient so I'm trying to 'tighten' it up using some sort of looping mechanism to generate and execute/invoke the appropriate statements.

I tried an approach suggested on a Microsoft site based on a ToList().ForEach() statement declared in the public Form() block then using tags to establish what I think of as a parent-child relationship between a row's checkbox and the other controls on that row.  I was not able to get that to work.

I've now created a method to be called when the checkbox state changes (it currently only addresses a single checkbox change but I'm presuming I can get the method to address all checkboxes using nested "if" statements and/or introducing additional variables):

```
private List<string> flushForm00()
{
    var flushFields = new List<string>();
    flushFields.Clear();

    if (placeLevelCheckBox00.Checked == false)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            string flushEachN = $"PlaceComboBox0{i}.Text = \"\";";
            //string flushEachT = $"TypeComboBox0{i}.Text = \"\";";
            Console.WriteLine(flushEachN);
            Console.WriteLine($"TypeComboBox0{i}.Text = \"\";");
            flushFields.Add(flushEachN);
            flushFields.Add($"TypeComboBox0{i}.Text = \"\";");
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            string flushEachC = $"placeLevelCheckBox0{i}.Checked = false;";
            flushFields.Add(flushEachC);
            Console.WriteLine(flushEachC);
        }
    }
```

The loop is iterating as intended as can be seen from Control.WriteLine output

```
PlaceComboBox00.Text = "";
TypeComboBox00.Text = "";
...
PlaceComboBox09.Text = "";
TypeComboBox09.Text = "";
placeLevelCheckBox01.Checked = false;
...
placeLevelCheckBox09.Checked = false;
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
```

As can also be seen from the output the list "flushFields" remains empty. I've tried playing with static/void on the method declaration line with no success.

I've successfully used the .Add() method elsewhere but not in a loop.  Why isn't the list being populated and is the loop code "fix-able" and if so how?

My apologies for how long this has grown to be.
Thank you in advance for your time and expertise.

Comment: Did you expect this line _Console.WriteLine(flushEachC);_ to print each string in the List? No it doesn't

Comment: Thanx Steve - yes I did.  It's the only approach I know for trying to determine if the list is actually being populated via the Add().  Is there another way?

Comment: A `List<T>` doesn't have any way to represent an object of type T in a string even if the objects themselves are strings. So when you call ToString() on it (Console.WriteLine calls ToString()) the list responds giving you back the object class name. The List has a Count property that tells you the number of elements or there is the IEnumerable extension called Any that returns a boolean. Anyway I think you need to redesign your approach. Too much complicated. Use arrays to store the objects that you want to manipulate

Comment: to see list content in run-time output: NuGet package YamlDotNet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A List doesn't have any way to represent each single object contained in the list as a string. Even if the objects themselves are strings. So when you call ToString() on it (and Console.WriteLine calls ToString()) the list responds giving you back the object class name. There are different ways to solve your problem. First, the List has a Count property that tells you the number of elements, then there is the IEnumerable extension called Any that returns a boolean (true if there is at least one element) or you can write your own class that derives from `List<string>` and implements a different version of ToString overriding the base functionality.

Said that, I think you really need arrays here. Instead of working on each single element by its name, put everything that needs to be changed by your code in an array. An array for CheckBox, one for Labels, one for TextBox etc. Each element of the array should be stored in the progressive position related to your indexing logic.
So, taking an example related to checkboxes, you could declare (at the form global scope) an array of CheckBoxes

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
     private CheckBox[] _myChecks;

     public Form1():base()
     {
         InitializeComponent();

         // Notice that this doesn't create another set of checkboxes.
         // It just stores the reference to the checkboxes created by 
         // InitializeComponent in an array
         _myChecks = new CheckBox[] 
         {
             placeLevelCheckBox00,placeLevelCheckBox01,placeLevelCheckBox02,
             placeLevelCheckBox03,placeLevelCheckBox04,placeLevelCheckBox05,
             placeLevelCheckBox06,placeLevelCheckBox07,placeLevelCheckBox08
         };
    }
```

At this point if you need to activate everything starting from index 0 to 4 and deactivate everything else you could write

```
private void HandleCheckboxes(int activateLimit)
{
   for(int x = 0; x <= activateLimit; x++)
       _myChecks[x].Checked = true;
   for(int x = activateLimit+1; x < _myChecks.Length; x++)
       _myChecks[x].Checked = false;
}
```

Of course you could expand these examples adding the other arrays and applying the logic required in the same loop where you activate/deactivate the checkboxes array

Now the last bit. How do you know the index position to use for activation/deactivation without looking at the variable name of each checkbox?
You can do that using the Tag property of each checkbox. This property could be used by the programmer to store data of any kind. You can store there the index to use for that particular checkbox (You could do this in the form designer inside each checkbox property list)

```
placeLevelCheckBox00.Tag = 0;
placeLevelCheckBox01.Tag = 1;
// and so on for the others
```

now everything is in place for the major improvement.
You could set the same event handler for every checkbox going to each checkbox property window and then choose the same handler for the CheckedChanged event in the event list. You don't need ten different event handlers doing the same thing

```
private void placeLevelCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Here sender is the checkbox clicked. Just need to cast it 
    int activateLimit = Convert.ToInt32((sender as CheckBox).Tag);
    HandleCheckboxes(activateLimit);
}
```

Comment: "Marked as Answer" qualifications: declaring private myChecks[] = new CheckBox[] in primary Form block not working; causes InitializingComponents(); to throw "} expected" error and many "invalid tokens" on the statement.  Putting array declaration in HandleCheckboxes method works.  "private void placeLevelCheckBox.CheckedChanged etc" is being interpreted by Visual Studio as an invalid interface.  Tried changing it to ... CheckBox00.Checked... (despite that invalidating purpose of method) but same result.  Actioning controls "slaved" to a Checkbox via "Tag" remains unclear.

Comment: The Tag property is availabe using the form designer properties windows (as well via code) for each checkbox. Just select one and look at the designer.

Comment: {A) Deleted the the "private" but now  myChecks[] = new CheckBox[] is giving "identifier expected", "name not found" & "cannot implicitly convert .CheckBox[] to 'myChecks[]'" errors.  Tried creating a instance of CheckBox[] with CheckBox[] myChecks = new CheckBox[] which doesn't error out but myChecks is not found in the Handle method. (B) Is there an implicit wildcard in placeLevelCheckBox_CheckedChanged to add the 00-09 suffix? Tried two explicit wildcards (* and %) in front of "_" but VS didn't like that.  Put a breakpoint on end of this method but step-through never activated.

Comment: Final comment on this: 4 VS IDE users, to get all the CheckBox events handled by placeLevelCheckBox_CheckedChanged utilize "(sender as CheckBox)" in place of specific control Name then in Designer associate all relevant controls with that event; SEE [link] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/how-to-connect-multiple-events-to-a-single-event-handler-in-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8